# How to change the default path for iTunes file sharing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ios5, itunes

iTunes files are bydefault stored to document directory. What if i want to create a folder named "itunes files" is document directory and save all files into them.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not possible in official sdk..

if you want to hide some of the files in your document directory then start their name from "." and make them hidden

Example -

```
.somefolder
.somefilename.txt
```

Comment: ok.That means iTunes files will forcefully be saved in document directory only and i can't put them in any other or new created folder?

Comment: what do yo exactly mean by iTunes files?

Comment: Files that i fetch when my ipad is sync with iTunes and use them in my app

Comment: ok.. there is no way to specify a path for them.. full documents direcotry will be shared

Comment: Ya I can see that in your profile.. Are you interested in reallocating to Jaipur? Actually we are looking for some iPhone programmers.. let me know if you are interested..

Comment: Thank you but Jaipur is too far and i don't want to relocate that far